# Wrapping radio buttons within a select list with rails form helpers

Tags: forms, search, ruby-on-rails-6

I’m struggling with the select button in search form. I'm trying to replicate what they have on [this website](https://www.rockwell.ch/) when you click on the budget select field. I want to create a dropdown which contains radio buttons with each a price range. If I’m able to send the price range through the :sell_price_from  and :sell_price_to to the params it would help elastic search to find the properties. So fare I’ve been only able to make either radio buttons (with f.radio_button ) or select dropdown (f.select ) but not both.

This is how my form looks like now:

```
<div class="w-full mx-4 pt-32">
  <div class="px-24">
    <div class="rounded-t-xl overflow-hidden p-4">
      <%= form_with model: @property, url: properties_path, method: :get, class: "", id: "search" do |f| %>
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <div class="flex-1 w-auto min-h-0 min-w-0">
            <div class="bg-white relative">
              <%= f.label :q, "Search by keyword", class: "absolute left-8 top-4 text-sm text-black" %>
              <%= f.text_field :q, placeholder: "Search", class: "text-base px-8 pt-10 pb-8 border-none bg-none outline-none w-full h-20 leading-8 font-light pb-0" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-1 w-auto min-h-0 min-w-0">
            <div class="bg-white relative">
              <%= f.label :sell_price, "Budget", class: "absolute left-8 top-4 text-sm text-black" %>
              <div class="text-base px-8 pt-10 pb-8 border-none bg-none outline-none w-full h-20 leading-8 font-light">

                <%= f.radio_button :sell_price_from, "100000" %>
                <%= f.label :sell_price_from, "100.000" %>
                <%= f.radio_button :sell_price_from, "200000" %>
                <%= f.label :sell_price_from, "200.000" %>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-1 w-auto min-h-0 min-w-0">
            <div class="bg-white relative">
              <%= f.label :type, "Type", class: "absolute left-8 top-4 text-sm text-black" %>
              <div class="text-base px-8 pt-10 pb-8 border-none bg-none outline-none w-full h-20 leading-8 font-light">
                <%= f.collection_select :property_type, PropertyType.all, :name, :name, {}, {class: "border-0"} %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-1 w-auto min-h-0 min-w-0">
            <div class="bg-white relative">
              <%= f.label :rooms, "Rooms", class: "absolute left-8 top-4 text-sm text-black" %>
              <div class="text-base px-8 pt-10 pb-8 border-none bg-none outline-none w-full h-20 leading-8 font-light">
                <%= f.select :rooms, ["2", "3", "4"], { }, {class: "border-0"} %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-none w-auto min-h-0 min-w-0">
            <div class="">
              <%= button_tag class: "bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 hover:bg-blue-400 focus:outline-none h-20 w-32 px-8 pt-10 pb-8 flex justify-center py-4 px-14 rounded-none text-base items-center whitespace-nowrap" do  %>
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is basically, how do I wrap radio buttons within a select dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the exampled dropdown containing a common label for an option those options are not separate see the example

In rails you can try this if you need it to be dynamic:

```
<%= f.label :sell_price_range, "#{sell_price_from}"+  " - " + "#{sell_price_from_to}" %>
```

[image]